# How to use cookies and sessions django

Tags: django, cookies

I a have a certain amounts of products. I want to make function that save a certain products in cookies not database. But i dont know how to create a list of product in cookies. Products mast be saved in such way from that i can show them by some function. What method i must use to create a list of products in cookies.

```
def add_instance_note(request,instance_id):
    instance = Instance.objects.get(pk=instance_id)
    request.session['list'].append(instance_id)
    return render_to_response('show_instance.html', locals(),
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def show_instance_note(request):
    instances=[]
    for instance_id in request.session['list']:
         instances.append(Instance.objects.get(pk=instance_id))
    return render_to_response('show_instance_note.html', locals(),
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use sessions with Django you must first enable and configure a session service, with a certain backend (in your case cookies). This is covered in depth here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions

For basic cookie support, this is available on the request/respond objects:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

You can set a cookie with `set_cookie`:

```
def GetHandler(request):
  response = HttpResponse('Testing cookies')
  response.set_cookie('key', 'value')
```

To get cookies, you retrieve them from `request.COOKIES`. You can use standard `dict` operations like `has_key` and `get` to retrieve them (by the key you set previously).